# Two limit problems

Tags: limits

For [this question](http://s16.postimg.org/j7n5evqfp/seq.jpg) I kind of got stuck on d) part:

> Define a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_+}$ recursively by $$a_1 = 1, \hspace{.2in} a_{n + 1} = 1 + \frac{1}{a_n}$$
>   Show that
>
> (a) $1 \le a_n \le 2 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_+$.
>
> (b) $\Big((a_{n + 2})^2 - a_{n + 2} - 1\Big)$ has the same sign as $\Big((a_n)^2 - a_n - 1\Big)$.
>
> (c) $(a_{2k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}_+}$ is a decreasing sequence and $(a_{2k - 1})_{k \in \mathbb{N}_+}$ is an increasing sequence.
>
> (d) $(a_{2k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}_+}$ and $(a_{2k - 1})_{k \in \Bbb{N}_+}$ converge to the same limit $\ell$. Deduce that $(a_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}_+}$ also converges to $\ell$. Find the value of $\ell$.

I said the first part directly follows by the shift rule. However, I am not sure how to deduce that An converges to the same limit L. It seems intuitive that if odd members and even members converge to L then the whole lot should do but how can I say it formally?

And the [next question](http://s16.postimg.org/klesa6pp1/seq2.jpg):

> Given $p \in \Bbb{N}_+$, set $a_n := \left(1 + \frac{p}{n}\right)^n$. Sow that $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{pk} = e^p$.

Any help how to show it?

Many thanks!

Comment: $|a_n-l|\leq \max(|a_{2E(n/2)+1}-l|,|a_{2E(n/2)}-l|$ Where $E(x)$ is the integer part of x (ie the only integer such that $E(x)\leq x \leq E(x)+1$)

Comment: Sorry but I don't actually understand that explanation :(

Comment: If I understood correctly, you already showed that $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ converge to the same limit $l$. Then what can you say about the quantities $|a_{2n+1}-l|$ and $|a_{2n}-l|$ ? Then consider my hint

Comment: Ok thx, I think I get it. Any thoughts about the second question?:)

Comment: If you have to use the previous question then no. Otherwise just take the log and find the limit

Comment: No, I don't need to rely on the previous question. I can, however, use the fact that the limit of (1+1/n)^n =e.

Comment: Then you have your answer

Comment: Do I? Does not seem that obvious to me T_T

Answer (score 0):

Since you already *know* both sequences (the with the odd indexes and the one with the even ones) converge (why?), you can apply arithmetic of limits:

$$a_{n+2}=1+\frac1{a_{n+1}}=1+\frac1{1+\frac1{a_n}}\implies\;\text{if}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty,\;n\;odd} a_n=\alpha\;,\;\text{then:}$$

$$\alpha=1+\frac1{1+\frac1\alpha}=1+\frac\alpha{\alpha+1}=\frac{2\alpha+1}{\alpha+1}\implies$$

$$\alpha^2-\alpha-1=0\implies \alpha=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}2\implies \alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\;\;\text{(why?)}$$

Note that **exactly** the same as above shows the sequence with even indexes converges to the same thing, and *then* the very same shows the general sequence converges to the same...

About the second question:

$$a_{pk}:=\left(1+\frac p{pk}\right)^{pk}=\left[\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k\right]^p\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}e^p$$

Comment: Thanks Sir, always saving me!